# How to set customer first name email template after creating new account in Magento 2

Tags: magento2.2, transactional-mail

I want to set customer first name on transactions email after create new customer account in magento2

I tried this line but that did not work

```
{{trans "Dear %name," name=$Firstname}}
```

Comment: try this `{{trans "Dear %first_name," first_name=$first_name}}` and https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-email.html

Comment: After using this code -{{trans "Dear %first_name," first_name=$first_name}} show only Dear, not first name

Answer (score 0):

try this

For Orders email:  {{var order.getCustomerFirstname()}} 
For Customers email: {{var customer.firstname}}